# Cron not works on mac osx and can not save

Tags: macos, cron, whenever

I use Rails 4 + whenever 0.9.2 on Mac os

But it didn't work at all. it seems never run the script

Whenever config file

```
every 1.minute do
  command "/Users/get_price_and_send_mail.rb"
end
```

Crontab

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/Users/get_price_and_send_mail.rb'
```

And If I edit the crontab manually, `crontab -e`
and save it with `wq!`

### "crontab.f3SIocnMWc" 5L, 349C written

Then `crontab -l` gave me the original result, it didn't changed.